# Am trying to add a dirctory assets in pubspec.ymal. but i get this error "Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/image/ (String)."

Tags: flutter, yaml, flutter-dependencies

Performing hot reload...
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Expected "assets" to be a list, but got -assets/image/ (String).
Exception: Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at .\pubspec.yaml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHz5w.png)

the hot reload should work

Answer (score 0):

Nvm i figured it out.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYpM5.png)

just add a space between - and assets like this:

```
- assets/image/
```